# How to get items from array by order

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

How can I take text from array and put it by order in my text. For now my text only shows last item in array.

Here is the code:

```
void Start()
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
    textMesh = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();

    for (int i = 0; i < slova.Length; i++)
    {
        string value = slova[i];

        textMesh.text = value;
        int random = Random.Range(0, slova.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: `textMesh.text += " " + value;`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a linq instruction like

```
void Start()
{
 this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sortingLayerName = "Foreground";
 textMesh = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
 textMesh.text = string.Join(" ", slova);
}
```

something like this:

[image]

Comment: Text is appearing but only last item from array,but i want show first,then second then third and etc

Comment: I ask how can i get first item to show in text,then on same text show the second item from array then after on same text show next item from array o ntext then next and so on,but not using shuffling or random but by order

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what you want to achieve. But if you want that textMesh.text should be appended with value, than you should use the following

```
textMesh.text += slova[i];
```

Comment: This will just add a text to text already.I want to update text which is on the object,and object is created from random,and.